# In Terminal, how do I access the hyperlink in hyperlinked text stored in the clipboard?

Tags: terminal, command-line, copy-paste

If I copy some text containing a hyperlink and then paste into another application that accepts it, then the text and its hyperlink is correctly copied over.

How can I access this hyperlink via the command line?  Using `pbpaste` or `pbpaste -Prefer rtf` just results in the text being pasted without the hyperlink.

For example if I copy the following text: "Some text with a [hyperlink](https://example.com) in it." from this webpage and then use `pbpaste -Prefer rtf` I see "Some text with a hyperlink in it." in the terminal but the https://example.com hyperlink is not shown anywhere / it is lost.  Is there a way to access this information from the clipboard in a terminal?  The data is there because if I paste into another application like the Notes application, the hyperlink will be present in the text pasted.

** Edit **

I am not expecting the output from pbpaste or any other tool to give a clickable link in the terminal.  I do not believe that is even possible for terminals to provide that.  I do want the hyperlink to come out in some standard format though.  To extend the example above, perhaps it is displayed as the following string of characters: `Some text with a [hyperlink](https://example.com) in it.` or whatever format can be parsed to extract the URL.

Alternatively just being able to access the raw string of bits/bytes on the clipboard and writing something to parse them myself would be fine too.

Comment: What do you mean with "text without the hyperlink"? Can you add an example?

Comment: @nohillside I think the OP means text (no hyperlink) vs. [text](https://www.oxley.com/domain/text.com/) (contains hyperlink).

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Maybe. Let‘s wait for the edit.

Comment: @ DavidSupportsMonica yes that's what I meant, thank you. @nohillside I have edited the question, I hope that helps clarify it. Thank you.

Comment: Is Terminal even able to show (and handle) hyperlinks?

Comment: I think you can use [xclip](https://linuxtect.com/linux-xclip-command-tutorial/) for this. This should allow you to do something like _xclip -out | grep 'foo'_ - basically running grep on the system clipboard. For the [RTF syntax of a hyperlink see e.g. this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850575/what-is-the-rtf-syntax-for-a-hyperlink).

Comment: @slartibartfast The problem isn't reading the clipboard in the shell (`pbpaste` does this), but formatting the hyperlink as a link.

Comment: AJP, do you have an example of shell/Terminal output which actually includes (formatted) hyperlinks? I'm 95% sure that they treat them simply as text because they don't even know what a hyperlink is.

Comment: @nohillside but xclip gives you the “pure” RTF and you pipe it to grep to just get _https ://www.*_ … or whatever. the OP wants to extract the URL from a RTF clipboard content, right?

Comment: @slartibartfast YOu can do that with pbpaste as well (I just tried). But as far as I understand, the OP wants it to formatted as a link (and most likely clickable). But neither shell nor Terminal know how to render or act upon a link.

Comment: @nohillside I missunderstood - I thought the OP has a problem with getting the actual link… to use it e.g. with Lynx  … the OP should state in detail what they want to achieve.

Comment: @slartibartfast no you had the correct understanding.  I have edited the question to clarify it again.  Thanks for everyone's comments.

Comment: so you have a variety of working solutions. great! 

Comment: use xclip or pbpaste and pipe it to grep as suggested and you should extract the link from clipboard: _xclip -out | grep '"http:*“ - as @nohillside stated, this should work similar with pbpaste. How exactly do you want to use/process the link extracted from RTf clipboard contents?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=match+http+link+with+grep might help.

Comment: Thanks @slartibartfast I can't get it to work with pbpaste.  Can you post an answer with an example please?  pbpaste just silently drops the URL from the copied text containing a hyperlink.

Comment: Whilst the _Terminal.app_ that ships with macOS cannot render hyperlinks, there are plenty of terminals that can: _iTerm_, _kitty_, _WezTerm_, ...  _iTerm_ and _kitty_ are my two go-to terminals programs, as they both allow actions to be taken on pasting that allow clipboard contents to be mutated based on what it contains.  Alternatively, many shells have a keybinding facility that allow custom functions to be called, say, when `⌃+V` is pressed, so you can write your own parsing facility.

Comment: This is also relevant: https://superuser.com/a/1104703/148811